# Remover diretório "public" do laravel 5 pelo web.config do IIS

Tags: laravel-5, iis, url-rewrite

Estou com um servidor IIS onde será hospedado um site construído em Laravel 5.3 e que eu preciso remover a pasta public da url.

**NOTA:** Tenho conhecimento que se eu entrar no gerenciador do IIS e alterar a pasta destino do site para a "wwwroot/meusite/public" este problema é solucionado mas, não tenho acesso a isso na hospedagem em que pago...

Minha única solução então, é usar regras de `rewrite mode` diretamente no arquivo **web.config** da pasta root do laravel o problema é que em uma ampla busca de soluções como essa na internet, só encontrei regras que funcionem quando o servidor é apache (.htaccess) alguém conhece alguma regra para remover a pasta public de uma aplicação Laravel de um servidor em IIS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu mesmo fiz um GIST para ajudar com isto https://gist.github.com/brcontainer/c2b3c75439fa3e4905e9 achei estranho não encontra-lo através dos buscadores de web, mas ok, vou trazer para cá.

Você pode colocar todo conteudo fora da pasta `%SYSTEMROOT%\inetpub\wwwroot`, e dentro de `wwwroot` colocar o conteúdo de `./public`.

No entanto é possivel colocar dentro tudo de `wwwroot`, incluindo `public`, basta criar na pasta `wwwroot` o arquivo `web.config` (fora de `public`) e coloque o seguinte conteúdo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Laravel Force public">
                    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Laravel Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public/index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Isto supondo que já tenha configurado o PHP, como FastCGI ou CGI

Comment: funcionou, deu um erro no começo mas era falta de permissão na pasta dentro do servidor, muito obrigado